Select value between two columns based on condition in pandas dataframe
Given the following dataframe:
d = {'one': pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40],
                      index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
     'two': pd.Series([0, 0, 25, 0],
                      index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


   one  two
a   10    0
b   20    0
c   30   25
d   40    0

How do I select the appropriate value based on the following if/else and populate it into a new column called df['three']?
df['three'] = If df['two']>0, select df['two'], else select df['one']

Basically, I am looking to have the final result as:
   one  two  three
a   10    0     10
b   20    0     20
c   30   25     25
d   40    0     40


df['three'] = df['one'].mask(df['two'] > 0, df['two']) should do the trick. It will replace the values from df one if the condition df['two'] > 0 is true.

I think you can use the DataFrame.where method for that
import pandas as pd

d = {'one': pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40],
                      index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
     'two': pd.Series([0, 0, 25, 0],
                      index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Use `two` column values if df.two column value > 0 else use `one` column values
df['three'] = df['two'].where(df.two > 0, df['one'].values)
print(df)


Is your df.two a typo?

@enter_display_name_here no I think it should work as expected, although you can also use df['two'] instead
